# different signature with same input openssl

Tags: openssl, public-key-encryption, signature, private-key, ecdsa

I'm using Openssl (`OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019`) and I want to sign a message.

```
$ echo foo > a.txt
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign chiave_priv_1.pem a.txt
EC-SHA256(a.txt)= 3045022100c7d6e61942d3104838b70cda870fb53870c36aa7075be518e9d0d098370d989802202dddd3e0fbba70be84d4540e20c43116cf0db1cee69b2ed422c9403cdac8bd54

$ openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign chiave_priv_1.pem a.txt
EC-SHA256(a.txt)= 3046022100fa1df4a9d3f07b0105e5923ef9c7a6f52dc5fa3b60beda7d1ed8a5eec805d3f402210097941741cdaa06ff650e48912eb05d37bc74aab8cf24951a543c88a357bb7f30
```

I repeat the signature twice and I get two different output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a DSA key, or an ECC key then the signature is randomized.  As far as I know, this is done on purpose.

If you use a RSA key, then it depends on your padding type.  The default padding is pkcs and should generate a deterministic signature.  If you change the padding type (e.g. -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss) then you will also get random results.

Comment: Thanks, I want to replicate Bitcoin's signature, it's ECDSA (ECC)

Comment: I don't know enough to answer that question.  All you can do is verify the signature is correct, you will not be able to re-generate the exact same signature.

Comment: @monkeyUser+ DSA and ECDSA signing are officially random per their standards (FIPS 186 and X9.62); it is possible to use a 'synthetic' k instead, see RFC 6979, and at least some Bitcoin software does, but OpenSSL does not. Bitcoin normally signs transactions, and when it does sign messages it modifies the input and changes the representation of the signature. And both types of Bitcoin signatures use _double_ SHA256 not the standard single which OpenSSL does, so you must adjust for that. Doing this by hand is hard, but there are dozens of Qs on bitcoin.SX about it you could read if you wanted.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks! I'd like to get signature by openssl, I will check documentation. thanks!